# Don't show pop up again if button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a pop up that will remind the user to read some documents. It will also include a button to confir whether they have read the relevant document or not.
This is my code so far :

```
<form runat="server">
  <div id="cookie_box">
    We have compiled a summary of the  Technical Mailings sent throughout 2015. To view the document,<a href="/cookies">  click here</a>
    <br /><br />
    I confirm that I have read the above document
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="confirmButton" Text="confirm" />
  </div>
</form>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (getCookie('show_cookie_message') != 'no') {
        $('#cookie_box').show();
    }

    $('.cookie_box_close').click(function() {
        $('#cookie_box').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, "slow");
        setCookie('show_cookie_message', 'no');
        return false;
    });
});

function setCookie(cookie_name, value) {
    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + escape(value);
}

function getCookie(cookie_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        cookie_start = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name + "=");
        if (cookie_start != -1) {
            cookie_start = cookie_start + cookie_name.length + 1;
            cookie_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", cookie_start);
            if (cookie_end == -1) {
                cookie_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(cookie_start, cookie_end));
        }
    }
    return "";


}
```

Now I want to implement a function that when the user clicks the `confirmButton` the pop up will not show up anymore (at all- even in a new session), but I'm not sure how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: assign a global variable with value 'no' and set it to 'yes' when the visitor clicks the confirm button, run the popup script if the global variable is set to 'no'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle this with a cookie and not rely on server state. Then you should definitely check out this library for accessing cookies with jquery.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Create session cookie:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value');
```

Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```

Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Read cookie:

```
$.cookie('name'); // => "value"
$.cookie('nothing'); // => undefined
```

you should basically query if a certain value is set in the cookie:

`if($.cookie('confirm')=== 'yes')...` // show or hide your box

**Note:** One important thing. You do not need a server side control if you are doing only client site scripting. (runat="server"). And if so you need to hook it up to process the client site event. Right now it posts back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need your click handler to attach to your asp:Button.

Try setting `<asp:Button CssClass="cookie_box_close" ID="confirmButton" Text="confirm" />`

Comment: cheers, forgot to do that- I've edited my Question as I think I wasn't quite clear. I need the pop up box not to show up at all anymore after clicking confirm. Even if the user comes back to the website another time

Answer (score -1):

try changing this code

```
$('.cookie_box_close').click(function()
{
    $('#cookie_box').animate({opacity:0 }, "slow");
    setCookie('show_cookie_message','no');
    return false;
});
```

to

```
$('.cookie_box_close').click(function()
{
    $('#cookie_box').animate({opacity:0 }, "slow", function(){
       var value = confirm( "Click 'OK' if you don't want pop-up again");
       if ( value )
       {
         setCookie('show_cookie_message','no');
       } 
    });

    return false;
});
```